# How to call only onAdloaded on Facebook Native Ads using normal Adlistener call all override

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

Please help me come up with a method where I can shorten the native ad code as it gets really confusing if I use more than one ad

```
try {
                    fbNativeAd = NativeAd(this@SplashActivity, fbNative)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }

                val nativeAdListener: NativeAdListener = object : NativeAdListener {
                    override fun onMediaDownloaded(ad: Ad) {
                        // Native ad finished downloading all assets
                        Log.e(TAG, "Native ad finished downloading all assets.")
                    }

                    override fun onError(ad: Ad, adError: AdError) {
                        // Native ad failed to load
                        Log.e(TAG, "Native ad failed to load: " + adError.errorMessage)
                    }

                    override fun onAdLoaded(ad: Ad) {
                        // Native ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
                        Log.d(TAG, "Native ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!")
                        inflateFbNativeAd(fbNativeAd!!)
                    }

                    override fun onAdClicked(ad: Ad) {
                        // Native ad clicked
                        Log.d(TAG, "Native ad clicked!")
                    }

                    override fun onLoggingImpression(ad: Ad) {
                        // Native ad impression
                        Log.d(TAG, "Native ad impression logged!")
                    }
                }

                // Request an ad
                try {
                    fbNativeAd!!.loadAd(
                        fbNativeAd!!.buildLoadAdConfig()
                            .withAdListener(nativeAdListener)
                            .withMediaCacheFlag(NativeAdBase.MediaCacheFlag.ALL)
                            .build())
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }
```

This is the code I'm using right now, how can I shorten it? Should I try to use Abstract listener? because when I did try to use it, it did not work. Can anyone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand your problem. Same problem with me.
Facebook sdk is not smart/flexible as comapred to Admob.

> **In `Facebook-Audience-Network`: You can not call single method of `AdListener` like `onAdLoaded` if you call single method then code
> will not work, You must be call all methods then it works.**

**You can shrink/short code in this way:**

LONG CODE:

```
override fun onMediaDownloaded(ad: Ad) {
                        // Native ad finished downloading all assets
                        Log.e(TAG, "Native ad finished downloading all assets.")
                    }
```

Short this useless code(in this way):

```
override fun onMediaDownloaded(ad: Ad) {}
```

Thanks

**Happy Coding:)**